# #1044 - Access denied for user 'A WEIRD USER'@'localhost' to database 'MY DATABASE'

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I have problem loading some data from a CSV file to my table in the database
and got an error said :

```
#1044 - Access denied for user 'A WEIRD USER'@'localhost' to database 'MY DATABASE'
```

As I know phpmyadmin logged in (Automatically when clicked on phpmyadmin icon in CPanel) as a user who doesn't have permission to run some queries 
and there is no button to log out from phpmyadmin and log in as my user

NOTE: this error is not only for load data from CSV file, but this error also comes on run some queries too!
NOTE 2: I don't use localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know its late
but I export my database and tables as SQL format "NOT CSV"
and it imported without a problem :)

Answer (score -1):

You can go around this importing the source tables, then copying the records into the target table.

Share more Info so I can help you

Comment: I think this should be more like a comment to the user question rather than an answer.

Comment: Thanks Moldovan Daniel, I think you're correct. Learning my way into stackoverflow